# Functional requirements and architecture

Tags: architecture

How does the key **functional** requirements affect software architecture?

when choosing an architectural pattern you usually do it based on the non-functional requirements. I would like to know how the functional requirements affect the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect that the functional requirements are ill defined or are bound to change , you choose a more flexible architecture. If they are very well defined or standards based, you can choose a stricter, less flexible one.

Comment: Thank you I can definitely use that in my presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Functional requirements does have say in decision of software architecture of the application. For example, type of application whether data intensive or computation expensive plays imp role in decision.

Comment: I would just think that data intensive and computation expensive is represented by the non-functional requirements. I.e performability

Comment: No, Lets  take a simple example. if user says activity A should be finished in y secs.
Is it a functional requirement or not?  Do we not need to consider this while deciding architecture of application.

Comment: Well I still would not call it a functional requirement if we go by the wikipedian definition "In systems engineering and requirements engineering, a non-functional requirement is a requirement that specifies criteria that can be used to judge the operation of a system, rather than specific behaviors. This should be contrasted with functional requirements that define specific behavior or functions."